# Using catch method within a forEach loop causes every loop to catch the error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Within an array of servers, I wish to sync a property of a user.  I cannot be sure of the permission level of the bot in each server, or if the user is in each server.

Using timeout as a placeholder, the bot succeeds in timing me out when I am in a server I do not own, but fails to do so when I own the server.  As this bot is in many servers, it is important that someone couldn't add the bot to their server, give it no permissions, and crash the bot or at least remove the functionality of the command.

```
            client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => {
                userObject.timeout(60 * 1000, 'test of function').catch((err) => {console.log(`Invalid perms to change property in ` + a.name);});
            });
```

The result if the command is done on a server where perms are correct, is a timeout on that server, and that server alone.  If it is done on a server where perms are incorrect, the following error code follows:

```
Invalid perms to change property in Archive of SpeedRun //Server I own and tested the command on
Invalid perms to change property in TetrisRunner //Normally works
Invalid perms to change property in Nohtarealzrvr //Normally works
```

It seems that catching a single error causes the bot to catch an error in every attempt.

A solution I have tried already, putting a `try{}catch(err){}` segment inside of the forEach loop:

```
            client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => {
                try {
                userObject.timeout(60 * 1000, 'test of function')
                }catch(err) {console.log(`Invalid perms to change property in ` + a.name);}
            });
```

If done in a server where perms are not present, this crashes the bot (As .timeout is done async and crashes before the end of the statement?) The crash is as follows:

```
C:\Protocol7\Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:687
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[50013]: Missing Permissions
    at handleErrors (C:\Protocol7\Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:687:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Protocol7\Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1072:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Protocol7\Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:913:14)
    at async _REST.request (C:\Protocol7\Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1218:22)
    at async GuildMemberManager.edit (C:\Protocol7\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:381:15) {
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: {
      communicationDisabledUntil: -,
      communication_disabled_until: -
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Missing Permissions', code: 50013 },
  code: 50013,
  status: 403,
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/-/members/-'
}
```

-edit:  This is how I'm getting `userObject`:

```
userObject = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call your array of Promises with dedicated API : Promise.all() or Promise.allSettled().

```
Promise.all(
  client.guilds.cache.map(c => 
    userObject.timeout(60 * 1000, 'test of function')
      .catch((err) => {...})
    )
  ).then(...)
```

Comment: Gave me the same result with both Promise.all(), and Promise.allSettled().

Comment: where is the actual call depending on the cache item ? All I can see is that userObject.timeout() is called multiple times but without any different parameters

Comment: The cache item was tricky, as at first I used a user object which doesn't work with guild commands, I am currently fetching the userObject with this code, "userObject = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);"  Where "args[0]" is a user id.

Comment: In the code you showed first, userObject is always the same value, so you are always calling the same endpoint (it seems). Could it be that you are executing a  command that only works one time ? Could you try to log more information on the called server for each loop ?

Comment: Don't be fooled by the catch printing a.name,  which is the correct endpoint name, but I think userObject call a different server that it appears in the catch

Answer (score 0):

When using a try/catch block, you must `await` a promise in order to catch any possible error.

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(async a => {
   try {
      await userObject.timeout(60 * 1000, 'test of function');
   } catch(err) {
      console.log(`Invalid perms to change property in ` + a.name);
   }
});
```

However, when doing async functions in a loop, it's best to use a for-of loop.

```js
for await (const guild of client.guilds.cache) {
   try {
      await userObject.timeout(60 * 1000, 'test of function');
   } catch(err) {
      console.log(`Invalid perms to change property in ${guild.name}`);
   }
}
```

Comment: The first one gave me the same problem as the original code, and the second one gave me the error, "for await (const guild of client.guilds.cache) {
                            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word"

Comment: What NodeJS version are you using?

Comment: Version v20.3.0